# SwiftUI: Cannot preview in this file - *.app may have crashed..but builds fine

Tags: swift, xcode, sqlite, crash

I have just completed a SwiftUI port of a simple Android app that I made (thanks everyone here for their help) but it will not preview in the canvas. It builds in the simulator and on my phone fine though.

It has something to do with calling my database select function in .onAppear as when I comment this part of the code out it works fine.

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct SoundPageView: View {

    var category: String
    var pageTitle: String
    var buttonRows = [ButtonData]()
    @State var btns: [[String]] = [[]]
    @State var translation: String = "Bahasa Indonesia"
    @State var gotValues: Bool = false

    var btn1: String = "First Button"
    var btn2: String = "Second Button"
    var btn3: String = "Third Button"
    var btn4: String = "Fourth Button"
    var btn5: String = "Fifth Button"
    var btn6: String = "Sixth Button"
    var btn7: String = "Seventh Button"
    var btn8: String = "Eighth Button"
    var btn9: String = "Ninth Button"
    var btn10: String = "Tenth Button"
    var btn11: String = "Eleventh Button"
    var btn12: String = "Twelfth Button"
    var btn13: String = "Thirteenth Button"
    var btn14: String = "Fourteenth Button"
    var btn15: String = "Fifteenth Button"
    var btn16: String = "Sixteenth Button"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(self.translation)")
            //    .italic()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .frame(height: 50)
                .padding(.horizontal, 4)
            HStack(spacing:0) {
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        playSound(sound: "\(self.category)_audio1", type: "mp3")
                        self.translation = self.btns[1][1]
                    }) {
                        if(gotValues==true) {
                            Text("\(self.btns[1][0])")
                        } else {
                            Text("\(self.btn1)")
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(SoundButton())
                    Button(action: {
                        playSound(sound: "\(self.category)_audio3", type: "mp3")
                        self.translation = self.btns[3][1]
                    }) {
                        if(gotValues==true) {
                            Text("\(self.btns[3][0])")
                        } else {
                            Text("\(self.btn3)")
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(SoundButton())
                    Button(action: {
                        playSound(sound: "\(self.category)_audio5", type: "mp3")
                        self.translation = self.btns[5][1]
                    }) {
                        if(gotValues==true) {
                            Text("\(self.btns[5][0])")
                        } else {
                            Text("\(self.btn5)")
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(SoundButton())
                    Button(action: {
                        playSound(sound: "\(self.category)_audio7", type: "mp3")
                        self.translation = self.btns[7][1]
                    }) {
                        if(gotValues==true) {
                            Text("\(self.btns[7][0])")
                        } else {
                            Text("\(self.btn7)")
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(SoundButton())
                    Button(action: {
                        playSound(sound: "\(self.category)_audio9", type: "mp3")
                        self.translation = self.btns[9][1]
                    }) {                            if(gotValues==true) {
                        Text("\(self.btns[9][0])")
                    } else {
                        Text("\(self.btn9)")
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(SoundButton())
                    Button(action: {
                        playSound(sound: "\(self.category)_audio11", type: "mp3")
                        self.translation = self.btns[11][1]
                    }) {
                        if(gotValues==true) {
                            Text("\(self.btns[11][0])")
                        } else {
                            Text("\(self.btn11)")
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(SoundButton())
                    Button(action: {
                        playSound(sound: "\(self.category)_audio13", type: "mp3")
                        self.translation = self.btns[13][1]
                    }) {
                        if(gotValues==true) {
                            Text("\(self.btns[13][0])")
                        } else {
                            Text("\(self.btn13)")
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(SoundButton())
                    Button(action: {
                        playSound(sound: "\(self.category)_audio15", type: "mp3")
                        self.translation = self.btns[15][1]
                    }) {
                        if(gotValues==true) {
                            Text("\(self.btns[15][0])")
                        } else {
                            Text("\(self.btn15)")
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(SoundButton())
                }
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        playSound(sound: "\(self.category)_audio2", type: "mp3")
                        self.translation = self.btns[2][1]
                    }) {
                        if(gotValues==true) {
                            Text("\(self.btns[2][0])")
                        } else {
                            Text("\(self.btn2)")
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(SoundButton())
                    Button(action: {
                        playSound(sound: "\(self.category)_audio4", type: "mp3")
                        self.translation = self.btns[4][1]
                    }) {
                        if(gotValues==true) {
                            Text("\(self.btns[4][0])")
                        } else {
                            Text("\(self.btn4)")
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(SoundButton())
                    Button(action: {
                        playSound(sound: "\(self.category)_audio6", type: "mp3")
                        self.translation = self.btns[6][1]
                    }) {
                        if(gotValues==true) {
                            Text("\(self.btns[6][0])")
                        } else {
                            Text("\(self.btn6)")
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(SoundButton())
                    Button(action: {
                        playSound(sound: "\(self.category)_audio8", type: "mp3")
                        self.translation = self.btns[8][1]
                    }) {
                        if(gotValues==true) {
                            Text("\(self.btns[8][0])")
                        } else {
                            Text("\(self.btn8)")
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(SoundButton())
                    Button(action: {
                        playSound(sound: "\(self.category)_audio10", type: "mp3")
                        self.translation = self.btns[10][1]
                    }) {
                        if(gotValues==true) {
                            Text("\(self.btns[10][0])")
                        } else {
                            Text("\(self.btn10)")
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(SoundButton())
                    Button(action: {
                        playSound(sound: "\(self.category)_audio12", type: "mp3")
                        self.translation = self.btns[12][1]
                    }) {
                        if(gotValues==true) {
                            Text("\(self.btns[12][0])")
                        } else {
                            Text("\(self.btn12)")
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(SoundButton())
                    Button(action: {
                        playSound(sound: "\(self.category)_audio14", type: "mp3")
                        self.translation = self.btns[14][1]
                    }) {
                        if(gotValues==true) {
                            Text("\(self.btns[14][0])")
                        } else {
                            Text("\(self.btn14)")
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(SoundButton())
                    Button(action: {
                        playSound(sound: "\(self.category)_audio16", type: "mp3")
                        self.translation = self.btns[16][1]
                    }) {
                        if(gotValues==true) {
                            Text("\(self.btns[16][0])")
                        } else {
                            Text("\(self.btn16)")
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(SoundButton())
                }
            }

        }
        .onAppear {
            let buttonRows = DatabaseHelper().queryDatabase(category: self.category)
            for each in buttonRows {
                self.btns.append([each.english,each.indonesian])
            }
            self.gotValues = true

        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(self.pageTitle), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}

struct SoundPageView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SoundPageView(category: "", pageTitle: "")
    }
}

struct SoundButton: ButtonStyle {

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .font(.custom("arial", size: 20))
            .padding(.horizontal, 4).minimumScaleFactor(0.9)
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(configuration.isPressed ? LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("DarkestGreen"), Color("LightGreen")]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom):LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("DarkGreen"), Color("LightGreen")]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .shadow(radius: 3.0)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth:2))
            .padding(2)
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.975 : 1.0)
    }
}
```

Here is the error message I'm getting in the canvas.

[image]

I would ideally like to call the database function before .onAppear but I'm not sure where to put it. When I create an init() a lot of errors are thrown. As I said, everything in the app works exactly as it should, I just don't want a crash error to be the reason my app is rejected by Apple. It's just a free app for my students and very simple.

Comment: You say it crashes, so what's the error message?

Comment: The canvas won't load and the error message is in the canvas, not the code. The error message is "Cannot preview in this file - (Appname).app may have crashed". The app doesn't actually crash. It's weird.